# Submitting without refresh AJAX

Tags: ajax, forms, submit, refresh

Ok I have seen a lot about submitting a form without refresh and I feel there are a couple of ways to do this with submit or just using a button (Difference/best?) and I am just still running into pproblems despite searching through countless posts. So:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var privacy = $('input:radio[name=privacy]:checked').val();
        var invites = $('input:radio[name=invites]:checked').val();
        var posts = $('input:radio[name=posts]:checked').val();
        var dataString = 'privacy=' + privacy + '&invites=' + invites + '&posts=' + posts;
        alert(dataString);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "editOptions.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function() {
                $('#admin').append("<div id='message'</div>");
                $('#message').html("Changes Saved");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

and:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="editOptions">

Privacy
<input type="radio" name="privacy" id="privacy" value="public" 
<?php if($privacy == "public") { ?>checked="checked"<?php } ?>> 
Public

<input type="radio" name="privacy" id="privacy" value="private" 
<?php if($privacy == "private") { ?>checked="checked"<?php } ?>> 
Private

Invites
<input type="radio" name="invites" id="invites" value="adminonly" 
<?php if($invite == "adminonly") { ?>checked="checked"<?php } ?>> 
Admin Only

<input type="radio" name="invites" id="invites" value="everyone" 
<?php if($invite == "everyone") { ?>checked="checked"<?php } ?>> 
Everyone

Posts
<input type="radio" name="posts" id="posts" value="adminonly" 
<?php if($post == "adminonly") { ?>checked="checked"<?php } ?>> 
Admin Only

<input type="radio" name="posts" id="posts" value="everyone" 
<?php if($post == "everyone") { ?>checked="checked"<?php } ?>> 
Everyone

<button>Save Changes</button>
</form>
```

So just a form with 3 sets of 2 radio buttons. So I think the problem is going through many tutorials and posts I have a combination of what to do when you either 'submit' or when you click a 'button' but maybe others can see something easy  I missed.

ty

EDIT editOptions just in case

```
<?php 
include 'config.php';

$privacyX = $_POST['privacy'];
$invitesX = $_POST['invites'];
$postsX = $_POST['posts'];
$groupAd = $_POST['groupName'];

$sql = "UPDATE `options` SET privacy='$privacyX', invite='$invitesX', post='$postsX' WHERE adminGroup = '$groupAd'";

if(!mysql_query($sql, $link))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); 
}

mysql_close($link);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full working example:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('.button1').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var privacy = $('input:radio[name=privacy]:checked').val();
                var invites = $('input:radio[name=invites]:checked').val();
                var posts = $('input:radio[name=posts]:checked').val();

                console.log(privacy, invites, posts);
                //return;
                //alert(dataString);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "editOptions.php",
                    data: {privacy: privacy, invites: invites, posts: posts},
                    success: function(result) {
                        $('#admin').append("<div id='message'>Changes Saved</div>");
                        console.log(result);
                        console.log("success");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="admin">
    </div>
    <form action="" method="post" name="editOptions">

        Privacy
        <input type="radio" name="privacy" id="privacy" value="public" > 
        Public

        <input type="radio" name="privacy" id="privacy" value="private" > 
        Private

        Invites
        <input type="radio" name="invites" id="invites" value="adminonly" > 
        Admin Only

        <input type="radio" name="invites" id="invites" value="everyone" > 
        Everyone

        Posts
        <input type="radio" name="posts" id="posts" value="adminonly" > 
        Admin Only

        <input type="radio" name="posts" id="posts" value="everyone" > 
        Everyone

        <button class="button1">Save Changes</button>
    </form>


</body>
```

Comment: Still not working unfortunately. When I alert(privacy') or any others it is always adminonly so I changed it back to:  var privacy = $('input:radio[name=privacy]:checked').val(); and it echos the right word but still just gives me a success message and doesn't change anything even though I checked and editOptions works fine.
Are these the right scripts? This is my first time with AJAX btw
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ias.min.js"></script>

Comment: I also have multiple forms on the page if that matters, they all use submit buttons though.

Comment: If you have multiple forms, the above code will create problems as all of the forms will call the same Ajax methods. In addition, From my side, it is very hard to tell what is wrong on server side code. let me check again

Comment: I have used a class for button. so your other forms will not effect with this code.

Comment: It's so weird I have exactly what you have copy and pasted yet it's still not changing my database values. I have tested with just submitting the form and editOptions works and when i put the ajax in it gives me the success message yet nothing i my DB table changes.
thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

All sorted. It was a problem with editOptions and not passing the right variable names.
:P
ty